# connection between php javascript for alert function with string

Tags: php, javascript, alert

I am working on site for users to do social netwoking. like facebook. or twitter. So far i have this code and let me show you what I want to do.

```
 <button id="welcome">Welcome user</button>
 <?php
     function dal(){
         alert("Hello user, welcome to my big social network")
     }
 ?>
```

and i do javascript like this

```
 <script>
     document.byID('welcome').onclick = dal();
 </script>
```

code currently is not working.

if you have any suggestion i really appreciate.

Comment: You will need to run through a basic tutorial. There is no byID in JS and you cannot dump a piece of JS in a php statement and expect it to be available to the client. Good luck with your Facebook killer

Answer (score 3):

Remove the php and write this inside `script` tag

```
<script> 
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
  function(){ 
    document.getElementById('welcome').onclick=dal;
  },false);
function dal(){
  alert("Hello user, welcome to my big social netowkr")
}
</script>
```

Comment: Likely better executed onload

Comment: Hmm, what's wrong with .onload? - I formatted your code a bit. It was not very readable

Comment: because i don't know to which element i should add .onload

Answer (score 1):

You can't call php functions in javascript.

Comment: That is not an answer, but a comment

Answer (score 1):

```
 <button id="welcome" onclick="dal()">Welcome user</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function dal()
  {
    alert("Hello user, welcome to my big social network")
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question really needs rewording. I honestly don't know where to start correcting the mistakes with this.... however to make the alert work for your button you need the following:

```
<button id="welcome">Welcome user</button>


<script>
  document.getElementbyID('welcome').onclick = function(){
   alert("Hello user, welcome to my big social network");
  }

 </script>
```

also you can't call or access PHP in JavaScript.

Please note the spelling mistake in your `alert` message too

Answer (score 1):

It is considered best practice to unobtrusively add the handlers in the head instead of inline

I suggest

```
<?php ... ?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('welcome').onclick=function() {
     alert("Hello user, welcome to my big social network")
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <button id="welcome">Welcome user</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but window.onload will run after every image and other files get loaded

Comment: That has never ever been a problem for me. But if that is too late, then your suggestion works in most modern browsers. Mine works in all browsers since document.getElementById was introduced